# How to prevent Action Post method called from Submit form Hit twice?

Tags: javascript

I have the following control in my **.cshtml** view:

```
<"a id="BtnSubmit" onclick="SubmitForm();"><img id="ImgSave" src="~/images/IcnSave.png" /></a>

    function SubmitForm() {
       $('#Form_Create_Edit_Customer_Contact_FollowUp').submit();
    }
```

Where `#Form_Create_Edit_Customer_Contact_FollowUp` is the name of the form.

The problem is that the corresponding controller POST method is being hit twice, how can I stop the current behaviour.

> Note: I need to use a link  rather than Button/Input with type submit for design reasons.

Comment: It's important to notice that SubmitForm() is called from the following control: <a id="BtnSubmit" onclick="SubmitForm();"><img id="ImgSave" src="~/images/IcnSave.png" /></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the current behaviour you can try below code

```
function SubmitForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $('#Form_Create_Edit_Customer_Contact_FollowUp').submit();
   }
```

Comment: Many Thanks, that solved the problem, however, can you please provide information of how calling e.preventDefault differentiates that e corresponds to the event of submitting the form, as SubmitForm() function is called from a <a> link rather than submit button??

Comment: I did not get about your query, Please elaborate